# Collection Views, Arrays, and Dictionaries

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary, collectionview

Trying to get my head around collection views, arrays, and dictionaries.  I have a class named CollectionViewCell that contains a UIImageView outlet that I want images from an array to populate.  The trouble is that I have different sections with different content so I created multiple arrays that store the images.  With the present code I get an error saying the array index is out of range.  Do I need to populate the different sections with a dictionary that separates the information with keys and values instead?

```
    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as CollectionViewCell

    // Configure the cell

    cell.imageView.image = green[indexPath.row]
    cell.imageView.image = blue[indexPath.row]

    return cell
```

How can I name the different sections with headers that are populated from an array?  names is my array of strings and HeaderView is a class containing an empty label.  I also get an error using this code.

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {

   switch kind {
    case UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader:
        let headerView =
        collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind(kind,
            withReuseIdentifier: "HeaderView",
            forIndexPath: indexPath)
            as HeaderView
        headerView.label.text = names[indexPath.row]
        return headerView
    default:
        assert(false, "Unexpected element kind")
    }
}
```

[edit]
The number of sections and number of items in section code:

```
    override func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    //Return the number of sections
    return 2
}


override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    //Return the number of items in the section
    return green.count
}
```

So if there's a different number of items in blue section as opposed to green, do I include return blue.count as well in the numberOfItemsInSection function?

Comment: Are green and blue supposed to populate different cells?  And could you also post your collectionView:numberOfItemsInSection: and numberOfSectionsInCollectionView: code?

Comment: Yep!  Green and blue have different elements in their arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Since `green` and `blue` are supposed to populate different sections, you need to use one or the other conditionally depending on the section, ex:

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    //Return the number of items in the section
    if section == 0 {
        return green.count
    } else {
        return blue.count
    }
}

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as CollectionViewCell

    // Configure the cell

    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        cell.imageView.image = green[indexPath.row]
    } else {
        cell.imageView.image = blue[indexPath.row]
    }

    return cell
}
```

In your current code, if `blue` is a shorter array than `green`, you can get the error you described, since the `numberOfItemsInSection` goes beyond `blue`'s index.

Answer (score 0):

The `indexPath` object encapsulates information not only about the row, but also about the section. So, if you are referring to the first element in the first section, the `indexPath.row` will be 0 and `indexPath.section` will be 0. If you are referring to the third element in the second section, `indexPath.row` will be 2 and `indexPath.section` will be 1 ... and so on. In this context, how would you define `cellForRowAtIndexPath`and `numberOfItems` methods? Here is the code:

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    //Return the number of items in the section
    if(section == 0) {
        return green.count
    } else if(section == 1) {
        return red.count
    }
}

tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell!) {
    //Reusable cell code
    if(indexPath.section == 0) {
          //green cell population
    }
    else if(indexPath.section == 1) {
          //red cell population 
    }
}
```